# How can you gracefully handle a user attempting to access a page they don't have permissions for?

Tags: google-app-maker

#### Is there a graceful way to handle permission failures?

If a user attempts to access an API endpoint or a link that they don't have access for, Appmaker currently just fails silently.

Is there an event that can be handled in the application and used to show a snackbar or other piece of UI that will tell the user that they don't have permission?

#### Can you query permissions directly from the user?

In a separate but related question I'd also like to know whether you can query the permissions directly and use an `if` statement to determine whether the user should even see certain pieces of UI or links.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so there's any graceful way to handle permission failures. On a second thought users should not see the Menu/Links which they don't have access to. So they don't accidentally click on that. Can you rework your use case in which users are accessing Links so that they won't have option to click on the link which they don't have access.

For your second point you can have the following code in your server script to check users roles. This should work for API end point as well.

```
//server script
function checkRole() {
 if (app.getActiveUserRoles().indexOf(app.roles.REPLACE) === -1) {
    throw new Error('Only users with XXX role can perform this action.');
  }
}
```